# What's the single word for "dangerous thing"?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

Can you please tell me what is the single word for "dangerous thing" that can be used here:

> He accidentally scarred his hand with a 'dangerous thing', but he still lives.

Comment: By "thing", do you mean a dangerous object like a bomb, knife, or gun, or a dangerous situation or activity like taking a selfie on a cliff edge, or a car with bad brakes?

Comment: Of course, its a dangerous object like a bomb, knife, or gun.

Comment: So you are talking about a *physical* thing? Please provide a sentence with a blank for the word you're looking for.

Comment: "He accidentally scarred his hand with a 'dangerous thing', but he still lives."

Comment: I don't think anyone would actually say that with some vague noun.  They'd say, "a knife" or "a hot iron" or "a lawnmower" not "with something dangerous." If they wanted to leave it vague, they'd just say, "In an accident"

Answer (score 2):

The danger of the “thing” is implied by the rest of the sentence. You can refer to it as a *hazard*, but that word would sit awkwardly in your sample sentence.

- He scarred his hand with the (thing). It’s a hazard.

> **hazard** *noun*
>   1.1 A potential source of danger.
>   ‘If you are confident that you understand the work, you can do the hazard identification and risk assessment yourself.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hazard)